# Play Dragon age Awakening non steam version with the Dragon Age:Origins steam version?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

Is this possible? I did research, and I found multiple people on forums saying that this is possible, but they don't explain how.

Answer (score 2):

Load Steam. On the bottom left there is an "ADD A GAME" link. Click on it and click on "Activate a product on Steam..."

Click NEXT, then I AGREE, then enter your "Dragon Age Awakening" NON-steam key. It should activate on Steam, and you should be able to download it from there as well.

Comment: That doesn't work. Steam doesn't accept my key as valid.

Comment: Lets assume your key is valid here, did you activate it on another system? I.e EAs web site? that might be why.

Comment: It is a new key, got it directly from my new Awakenings PC box. Never activated it before anywhere else.

Comment: This won't work. Here is a list of the games you can activate on steam: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601